# angular 2 routing subscription change detection

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-observables, angular2-changedetection

Given this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getBlogPosts().subscribe(blogPosts => {
        this.allBlogPosts = blogPosts;

        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    }));
}
```

I am trying to understand why I am forced to use `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();`

The circumstances are that if I load my blog route for the first time, my posts load fine, if I `route` to another page (either another `component` or the same "blog" `component` to show the details of a particular post (e.g. 'blog/my-post')) then I `route` back to the "blog" component at the root ('blog/'), this time, the template fails to update with the posts. I can see in my `Inspect`, `Network` tab, that the route to get the posts is still working, `console.log` is showing that all seems well through-out, however the template fails to update unless I force change detection. Is this expected behavior? Can it be remedied? This seems strange...

Another thing worth noting is that both first time and the 3 time that I visit the "blog" `component` I use:

```
this.router.navigate([`/${url}`]);
```

To navigate to it... and this can not be helped...

**Edit:** the `getBlogPosts()` method is in my `ApiService` that I inject into my `BlogComponent`:

```
public getBlogPosts() : Observable<BlogPost[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${ environment.apiUrl }GetBlogPosts`, { headers: this.headers })
                    .map((response: Response) => <BlogPost[]>response.json());
}
```

Comment: what is `this.apiService.getBlogPosts()`? show code for it

Comment: Sure, take a look at the edit. Your time is much appreciated.

Comment: _I route back to the "blog" component at th_ - how do you do that?

Comment: via a link that is outside of the ng app. via JS push it to the `Subject`: `onclick="window.routerSubject.next('our-services'); return false;"` that in my ng app, I assign in the `constructor`: `window.routerSubject = this.routerSubject;` and in the `ngOnIinit` I `subscribe` to my `Subject`: `this.routerSubject.subscribe((url: string) => {
            this.router.navigate([`/${url}`]);
        });`

Comment: try the following `this.routerSubject.subscribe((url: string) => { NgZone.run(() => this.router.navigate([/${url}]); });`, let me know if fixes it

Comment: that's actually `NgZone.call` but otherwise that worked! Awesome! Leave it as an answer so I can give you some credit, especially if you explain why that fixes it.

Comment: I posted an answer, see if makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses `NgZone` to get notified whenever the change detection cycle should be run. `NgZone` uses `zone.js` under the hood that intercepts all async operations like `setTimeout`, `new Promise`, `XHR` requests etc. So usually it works without any additional efforts from the developer.

However, if you some operation that is not catched by `zone.js` you don't get change detection triggered and have to do that manually. But you can use `NgZone` to execute some action in the Angular zone meaning Angular will run change detection after the callback has finished executing.

So in your case you can try something like this:

```
this.routerSubject.subscribe((url: string) => { NgZone.run(() => this.router.navigate([/${url}]); });
```

where `NgZone` can be injected into any Angular component or service:

```
constructor(zone: NgZone) {}
```

Comment: @SerjSagan, you're welcome) follow [me on medium](https://blog.angularindepth.com/)